# How to fix a display tinted blue and blurry?

Tags: display, graphics, display-driver

My display is blue tinted and blurry and I'm not sure what to do with it. Am I supposed to check the display drivers or format and reinstall the whole PC?

Please someone help me with some advice, I'm stuck. One minute it's ok and the next it's broken.

[image: example of the display]

Comment: What is your "ecran" ?  Do you mean screen ?  I think the reason you have no interest in the question is because no one knows what an ecran is - yet it does not seem to be a typo.  Also, can you advise more about the hardware and software you are using ?

Comment: Sorry for my english ecran is screen.

Comment: Im using a toshiba satellite l855-166

Comment: Is it laptop or desktop? @user3648216

Comment: @Davidenko thats a laptop.

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if your videocard is broken, but it can also be a driver issue.

You definitely should reinstall your videocard driver first. If you reboot your pc and you see the same kind of graphics glitches in the BIOS (or startup screen) it is a hardware problem.

If this is only on an external monitor and not on your laptop screen, make sure the cable and monitor are still fine.

If this also glitches in the BIOS or loading screen, it may be that your laptop needs to be replaced as either the videocard or screen is broken, two components that are likely not to be replaced easily.